# Retrieve featured image

Tags: images, mysql, android

We are building an Android app based on a Wordpress mysql database. We were able to get most of the information from the datase to display on to the app. Now all we have left is to retrieve the posts featured image.

Is there a way to have the featured image output a URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The featured image attachment id is stored in the post_meta table, with the meta_key `_thumbnail_id`.

Use that post id to find the post meta with meta_key `_wp_attachment_metadata`.

The value of that is a serialized array with keys `thumb`, `file`, `width`, `height`, `sizes` (an array), and `image_meta` (an array).

The `file` value is relative to the uploads directory for the WP install, and points to the original full-sized image. You should be able to calculate the URL from that.

`sizes` has an image size as its key (e.g., 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'thumbnail'), and the value is an array with keys `file`, `height`, and `width`.

`image_meta` will contain things like exif/iptc image metadata from the image itself.

Answer (score 7):

The post thumbnail is a stored in the `{$wpdb->prefix}_postmeta` table with the key `_thumbnail_id`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * from {$wpdb->prefix}_posts 
WHERE ID in (
   SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_postmeta 
   WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
   AND post_id = ':ID'
);
```

Replace :ID with the post id.

That will return the Post associated with the image itself -- the `post_title` will be whatever the user associated with the title attribute on the image, and the `guid` will be the full sized image URL.

If you want different sizes, you'll have to look up the `_wp_attachment_metadata` postmeta value which will contain a serialized array with all the different sizes.

Using WordPress' api is much easier:

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail($some_post_id))
{
   $img = wp_get_attachment_img_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($some_post_id), 'the_image_size');
   // returns an array, the first item is the image URL
   echo $img[0];
}
```

Comment: Don't depend on the `guid` field to be a URL ... it's meant to be a unique identifier, **not** a link.

Comment: That's a good point!  Is there' a field that stores that actual image URL outside of the `_wp_attachment_metadata` postmeta field?

Comment: That's what we are trying to figure out... I've found the actual image file on the database, but we need a way to call the image inside the sql query.

Comment: Take a look at [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/_functions/wp_get_attachment_url.html) and how it builds the URL for attached images based on the ID ...

Answer (score 5):

The post's featured image is a regular old attachment to the post.  So, as with any other image attachment, you'll need to query the `wp_posts` table for a post type of `attachment`.  The trick is to first get the attachment ID that you need to grab.

This is contained in the given post's meta information, specifically the `_thumbnail_id` meta.

So, you'll need a query that:

1. Retrieves the value marked by the key `_thumbnail_id` in the `wp_postmeta` table based on a given post ID.
2. Retrieves the attachment from the `wp_posts` table based on the ID retrieved in step #1
3. Generates an attachment permalink based on the information retrieved in step #2

Really, though, you're doing a lot of work to reinvent the wheel here ...

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I used to retrieve post data, featured image URL and feature image details (such as dimensions):

```
SELECT p.*, ( SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS imgurl,  (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm WHERE meta_key='_wp_attachment_metadata' AND pm.post_id=m.meta_value ) AS imgdetails
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta m ON(p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id' )
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish' AND p.id=@postId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use next query to retrieve the featured images of all posts:

```
SELECT result.post_parent, result.guid AS featuredImage
FROM wp_posts AS p 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts as result ON pm.meta_value = result.ID
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND p.post_type='post' AND 
p.post_status = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 1):

The best SQL solution,

Search the ID from wp_post

`SELECT  * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish'`

Found the meta content

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_thumbnail_id' AND post_id=MyID`

With the thumbnail ID, search one more time into wp_postmeta the file

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_wp_attached_file' AND post_id=MyID
```

Here one example.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER  BY id DESC LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error());
    $json='{ "Blog" : [ ';
    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $queryMeta=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_thumbnail_id' AND post_id=$row[ID]") or die(mysql_error());

        $f=mysql_fetch_array($queryMeta);

        $value=$f[meta_value];

        $queryMeta2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_wp_attached_file' AND post_id=$value") or die(mysql_error());

        $f2=mysql_fetch_array($queryMeta2);

        $value=$f2[meta_value];

        $json.='{"id" : "'.$row[ID].'" ,  "date" : "'.$row[post_date].'", "title" :"'.$row[post_title].'", "link" : "'.$row[guid].'" ,  "image" :"https://dartesanos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/'.$value.'" },';

    }
    $json=substr($json,0,-1);

    echo $json ."]}";
```

Comment: It's better to use json_encode(), $row[post_date] would produce notices/warnings because the key is not in quotes